# What does "low-speed USB device" mean?

Tags: usb

I've got Plymouth disabled so I see anything that happens at bootup. I noticed the following:
- When plugging my USB mouse, it says something like "New full-speed USB device connected"
- When plugging the gamepad I got on christmas , it's saying "low-speed USB device"
Can you confirm that full-speed means USB 2.0 and low-speed means USB 1.1 (I guess USB 3.0 would be super-speed, don't have SS-USB ports)

I'm asking because the packaging of the gamepad tells it's USB 2.0. Note: I can't check on `lsusb`, because it tells me "Failed to enumerate..." and it's not working both on Ubuntu and on Windows. I guess it came broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full-speed and low-speed does not mean that the device has a USB 1.1 or 2.0 interface. An USB 2.0 device can also use low-speed data rate. Low-speed is about 1,5 Mbit/s and I think for a gamepad there is no more speed necessary.

You kernel seems to recognize the device, but `failed to enumerate` is a bad sign. It can mean that the device is broken...
But first, you can try to disable the ehci host-controller by the following terminal commands:

```
cd /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/
sudo sh -c 'find ./ -name "0000:00:*" -print| sed "s/\.\///">unbind'
```

Then plug in the device again.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However the device is still not working. I'ts not even running on Windows which it was designed for.